# Função que adiciona/remove elemento do array ao clicar em checkbox no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho uma checkbox que ao ser clicada devo adicionar/remover esse elemento dependendo da ação.

Tentei algo como:

```
  adicionaProdutoSelecionado(produto,event){

    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.produtosSelecionados.push(produto);
    }
    if (event.target.checked === false) {
      this.produtosSelecionados = this.produtosSelecionados.filter((produto) => produto !== produto);
    }
  }
```

Quando eu realizo o uncheck o meu produtosSelecionados fica vazio, deveria retirar o elemento que foi clicado, apenas.

Onde estou errando?

Esse é meu template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let produto of sortedDataProduto; let i = index">
  <td>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input (click)="adicionaProdutoSelecionado(produto, $event)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked{{i}}">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked{{i}}"></label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

## front html

```
 <input (click)="adicionaProdutoSelecionado(produto, $event.target.checked, i)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked{{i}}">
```

## back ts

```
  adicionaProdutoSelecionado(produto,event,i){

    if (event) {
      this.produtosSelecionados.push(produto);
    }else
      this.produtosSelecionados.filter(item => item.id != produto[i].id);
    }
  }
```

remove o item pesquisando algum elemento do array, você pode trocar o "ID", para alguma informação que quiser

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, se uma variável é booleana apenas coloque-a no seu if, não há necessidade de uma comparação explícita. Segundo, evite comparar objetos inteiros como em `produto !== produto`, use seus Ids ou algum outro atributo, e tente não usar o mesmo nome para variáveis locais e globais.

```
  adicionaProdutoSelecionado(produto, event){

    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.produtosSelecionados.push(produto);
    } else {
      this.produtosSelecionados = this.produtosSelecionados.filter(item => item.id !== produto.id);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adicionaProdutoSelecionado(produto,event){

    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.produtosSelecionados.push(produto);
    }
    if (event.target.checked === false) {
      var index = this.produtosSelecionados.findIndex(produto);
      this.produtosSelecionados.Splice(index,1);
    }
  }
```

Eu acho que agora vai funcionar, porque é necessário pegar o index em qual o seu produto está para depois remover ele do array.